# You're not feeling well. You need something.

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

You're not feeling good. Something is horribly wrong with you. You're trying hard to feign happiness, but...

> ...deep inside, you feel dead.
>   ...deep inside, you are hurt.
>   ...deep inside, you know you are hated.
>   ...deep inside, you are all alone.
>
> Forward, and backward. The paths meet.

You need something. What's it? You should let the stars spell it out.

[image: Puzzle-image]

Comment: Story of my life...

Comment: @Sid Then you should solve this to find out what exactly you need :P

Comment: You're right, I DO need Pixar!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I know what you need ...

> [All you need is **LOVE**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsxtImDVMig)

We get this by ...

> continuing on from where [Wu33o](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/46632/30633) got, and then realizing that you find where the two lines for each word intersect.  The letters already provided align with a QWERTY keyboard.  Find where those intersections lie on the keyboard, in the order they appear in the rhyme, and you have:
>  The lines for **DEAD** meet at $\bf{L}$
>  The lines for **HURT** meet at $\bf{O}$
>  The lines for **HATED** meet at $\bf{V}$
>  The lines for **ALONE** meet at $\bf{E}$
>
>  Image from OP:
>   [image: Image from OP]
>  So you need **LOVE**.

Comment: Of course... *facepalm*. Good job :)

Comment: Can you do me a big favor and add a visual please?

Comment: @Mithrandir Wu33o already provided the visual in another answer; just look where like-colored lines intersect, mentally superimpose the entire visual above your keyboard, and see which letters are at those intersecting points.

Comment: I'm no good at mentally superimposing...

Comment: Great job all! @Mithrandir I've added an image for better visualisation; hope this makes things a bit clearer. :)

Comment: Too bad I use a different keyboard layout.

Answer (score 42):

Partial answer:

```
Forward, and backward. The paths meet.
```

> The four words at the end of the sentences in the poem can be found in the stars, forward and backward. We have:
>  O**DE AD**ROIT, ONE-EYE**D AED**ES
>  OLAUDA**H URT**ICATION, ADROI**T RUH**R
>  ALP**HA TED**GLOBAL, O**DE TAH**ITI
>  TEDGLOB**AL ONE**-EYED, M**EN OLA**UDAH

When we connect these words, we get the following lines:

> [image: Image with connections]

We can see that the places where the paths meet are all:

> On the same height as at least one of the letters. The first intersection is on the height of the A, the second and fourth intersection on the height of the R, I and P, and the third intersection on the height of the X.

And that's where I'm stuck for now :(

Answer (score 3):

Don't have an answer as of yet, just some observations.

...deep inside, you feel dead.

> RIP is spelt in the letters which correlates with death.

...deep inside, you are hurt.

> Within the letters RIP the one-eyed star could be a reflection of hurt. i.e. it has one eye.